# Scaling variables without hindering binary values of the data set

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to prepare a data set to train an ANN model, therefore I need to apply scaling. However some of my variables are continous and some are already in a binary form. Below an example of how a given row from my X_train data set looks like:

```
array([[0.0, 1.0, 654, 1, 40, 5, 105683.63, 1, 1, 0, 173617.09]])
```

I have applied the following code to normalize my values:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
```

However, this returns me an array with also the scaled binary values. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) with the [Column Transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer) for mixed types. Here is a [good example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) of how to apply different preprocessing and feature extraction pipelines to different subsets of features.